# Music player time slider is "laggy"

Tags: javascript, html, css, time, slider

I'm new here so maybe my question will be a bit difficult to understand.

So here's the problem:

I have built a website for myself in html, JavaScript, and css which includes a music player.
It's not ready yet cause I have many problems with it. But let's focus on the main problem.

So like every other music player application, mine also has a time slider. The main function would be to display the current song's current time and to make me able to skip it wherever I want. I guess you know what I mean despite my english level.

The skip part is working just fine. Not perfect but okay for now.
But the slider's movement is weird. It starts okay in the first few seconds, but after it beginst to take more and more time to jump to the next point.

This is the skipping part's code:

```
let slider = document.getElementById("durationSlide");
function changeDuration(){
    //console.log("currentTime: " + currentSong.currentTime);
    sliderPosition = currentSong.duration * (slider.value / 100);
    currentSong.currentTime = sliderPosition; 
}
```

And this would be the part where I was supposed to just follow the little dot along the slide 'till the end, but it stops after a while:

```
function rangeSlider(){
let position = 0;
if(!isNaN(currentSong.duration)){
    position = currentSong.currentTime * (100 / currentSong.duration);
    slider.value = position;
}

if(currentSong.ended){
    currentSong.currentTime = 0;
    currentCounter += 1;
    position = 0;
    PlayFunction();
}
```

}

UPDATE:

my code is pretty messy...

The function where it is called in every second. (I hope)

```
function PlayFunction() {

timer = setInterval(rangeSlider, 1000);
playIcon.style.display = "none";
pauseIcon.style.display = "inline";
songList[currentCounter].classList.add("current");
//console.log(songList[currentCounter].classList);
titles.innerHTML = songList[currentCounter].title;
songCounter.innerHTML = currentCounter+1 + "/" + document.getElementsByTagName("audio").length;
checkCurrent();
```

}

And the html for the slider:

```
<div class="duration">
    <input class="durSlider" id="durationSlide" type="range" min="0" 
              max="100" value="0"
              onchange="changeDuration()">
</div>
```

[testimg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6A9M.png)
from 0 to 10-13 seconds it goes fine but after it starts to skip time.
And every time I click on pause it jumps to the position where it supposed to be.

Comment: Please remove unneeded text, and focus on your question. Your post is a bit of a mess right now.

Comment: I've update the code snippet with some ideas you might try. Sorry I wasn't able to solve it for you, but it seems like a fun project and I'm sure that you will learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to work fine as I could not duplicate the problem. The lag you see is probably related to how your code interfaces with the audio player and the browser UI. If you are using a timer loop to update the UI, then one change that might help is switching to event based updates. As shown in the code snippet below, the audio player has a number of events you could use to update the position and duration. For example, this event handler would allow your audio player to update the UI with the position changes.  If you haven't read it already, MDN has a very nice walkthrough on using the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API)

```
currentSong.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e) {
  if (!busy) {
    position.value = currentSong.currentTime;
    positionText.innerHTML = toTimeString(currentSong.currentTime);
  }
});
```

```js
// Original Code

let slider = document.getElementById("durationSlide");

function changeDuration() {
  sliderPosition = currentSong.duration * (slider.value / 100);
  currentSong.currentTime = sliderPosition;
}

// And this would be the part where I was supposed to just follow the little dot along the slide 'till the end, but it stops after a while:

function rangeSlider() {
  let position = 0;
  if (!isNaN(currentSong.duration)) {
    position = currentSong.currentTime * (100 / currentSong.duration);
    slider.value = position;
  }

  if (currentSong.ended) {
    currentSong.currentTime = 0;
    currentCounter += 1;
    position = 0;
    PlayFunction();
  }

}

// Code used for testing 

var busy = false;

// fired when media properties like duration are known
currentSong.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
  position.max = currentSong.duration;
});

// do not update value when user is trying to change it
currentSong.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e) {
  if (!busy) {
    position.value = currentSong.currentTime;
    positionText.innerHTML = toTimeString(currentSong.currentTime);
  }
});

currentSong.addEventListener("ended", function() {
  position.value = 0;
});


// user is setting position
position.addEventListener("input", function() {
  busy = true;
  positionText.innerHTML = toTimeString(position.value);
});


play.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (currentSong.paused) {
    currentSong.play();
    play.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    currentSong.pause();
    play.classList.remove("active");
  }
});


position.addEventListener("change", function() {
  busy = false;
  currentSong.currentTime = position.value;
})

// volume 0.0 to 1.0
volume.addEventListener("input", function() {
  currentSong.volume = volume.value;
  volumeText.innerHTML = (100 * volume.value).toFixed() + "%";
});


function toTimeString(sec) {
  return new Date(sec * 1000).toISOString().slice(11, -5);
}
```

```css
#play:after {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  content: ">";
  /* play symbol */
}

#play.active:after {
  content: "II";
  /* pause symbol */
}
```

```html
<h3>Demo</h3>

<p>Click the play button and use the position and volume sliders.</p>

<audio id="currentSong" src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3"></audio>

<div style="padding:2px;margin:5px;">
  <button id="play"></button>
</div>
<div>
  <div>Position:</div>
  <input type="range" value="0" id="position" />
  <span id="positionText"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <div>Volume:</div>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" id="volume" />
  <span id="volumeText"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I recreated the code using the methods you were suggesting (sometimes even copied) but it still stops after a few seconds.